# OSError: Unable to open file (file signature not found) - Streamlit

Tags: python, github, streamlit

I have been working on a project locally using streamlit library. It is working fine locally and the page is opened with no error. once I deployed the files in github and streamlit cloud, I am facing this issue as attached in the image.

[image: the code where the error exist]
[image: the error in streamlit]

[Github repo](https://github.com/Mustafa-Alhussain/Frontal-Face-Detection)

your help is really appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure the file `model_gen.h5` exists?

Comment: yes sir, it is there in the github repo as attached here.

https://github.com/Mustafa-Alhussain/Frontal-Face-Detection

Comment: Did you solve it? What about adding a print(...) for ROOT_DIR and for the join-ed version in order to see what the actual path was.
Maybe ROOT_DIR was not what you thought it was.